# how to change area in magento 2

Tags: admin, frontend, magento2.3.4, area

I have tried this but this haven't worked for me

````
{
    if (isset($this->_areaCode)) {
        throw new MagentoFrameworkExceptionLocalizedException(
            new MagentoFrameworkPhrase('Area code is already set')
        );
    }
    $this->_configScope->setCurrentScope($code);
    $this->_areaCode = $code;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

By catching the exception Magento throws and silently ignoring it.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
    $name=null
) {
    try {
        $appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    } catch (MagentoFrameworkExceptionLocalizedException $e) {
        // intentionally left empty
    }
    parent::__construct($name);
}
```

Or

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$area = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
if (!$area->getAreaCode()) {
    $area->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
}
$currentAreaCode = $area->getAreaCode();
```

Comment: Using `objectManager` is not recommended and its considered bad practise. Inject the desired class into your own class and then use it without calling the `objectManager`on it.